# SQL header in result file

Tags: sql, oracle, shell

I have a SQL script:

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRUNCATE ON
SET VERIFY OFF

select
  count(case when msg_id like 'R%' and corr_id like 'F%' then 1 end) as Fid_Incoming ,
  count(case when msg_id like 'E%' and corr_id like 'F%' then 1 end) as Fid_Outgoing,
  count(case when msg_id like 'R%' and corr_id like 'E%' then 1 end ) as Equi_Incoming ,
  count(case when msg_id like 'E%' and corr_id like 'E%' then 1 end) as Equi_Outgoing
 from tb_msg
 where soc_id = 'WINDOWS'
 and msg_date >= trunc(sysdate);
 quit
```

That returns the following if called from sqlplus:

```
FID_INCOMING FID_OUTGOING EQUI_INCOMING EQUI_OUTGOING
------------ ------------ ------------- -------------
       0            0             0             0
```

But if I call the SQL from a shell script:

```
 sqlplus -s /@$TWO_TASK @${SQLDIR}/SWID_msgChecks.sql 1>${OUTPUT} 2>$1
```

The column names are not written to file, how do I get the headers/column names written to file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must not be calling it correctly from SQL*Plus because you've specifically `SET HEADING OFF` and `SET PAGESIZE 0` which disabled the column headers.

From [this reference document](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html):

```
HEA[DING] {OFF|ON}
   print column headings

PAGES[IZE] {14|n}
   The height of the page - number of lines.
   0 will suppress all headings, page breaks, titles
```

When you're calling SQL*Plus from the shell script, you're getting exactly what you've specified that you want (i.e. no headings).  If you want the headings to stay, you should use `SET HEADING ON` and set `PAGESIZE` to some non-zero value.